# Overcoming incompatibilities between tensorflow 1.x and 2.x when trying to view layer activity with backend

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, libraries

I would like to run newer tensorflow routines like:

```
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
```

for which I get error in 1.x:

ImportError: cannot import name image_dataset_from_directory

while preserving older functionality of 1.x like running the routine to see activations in various layers like:

```
    K=tf.keras.backend
    func = K.function([base_model.input, K.learning_phase()],[layer.output for layer in base_model.layers if layer.output is not base_model.input])
```

for which I get the following error in tf 2.x:

ValueError: Input tensors to a Functional must come from `tf.keras.Input`. Received: 0 (missing previous layer metadata).

The code:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

    IMG_SHAPE = (160, 160) + (3,)
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                   include_top=False,
                                                   weights='imagenet')

    K=tf.keras.backend
    func = K.function([base_model.input, K.learning_phase()],[layer.output for layer in base_model.layers if layer.output is not base_model.input])
```

The documentation I looked at suggests the problem may have something to do with eager computation mode eg https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34201

But I cannot figure out how to resolve this.
Thank you for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [#34201](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34201#issuecomment-557308250), Just disable the eager execution and run the rest of your code

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory

IMG_SHAPE = (160, 160) + (3,)
base_model = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE,
                                                   include_top=False,
                                                   weights='imagenet')

K=tf.keras.backend
func = K.function([base_model.input, K.learning_phase()],[layer.output for layer in base_model.layers if layer.output is not base_model.input])
```